# How can I load HTML into Angular 2 and execute script tags?

Tags: ajax, angular

To help transition our app to Angular, we're creating an outer Angular wrapper that dynamically loads server rendered HTML. Using `http.get` and `<div [innerHtml]="result"...` in my template works fine for HTML, but it strips `<script>` tags. I've tried injecting [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) and using `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` which then renders the script tags, but still does not execute them.

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547505/angular-2-how-to-execute-script-tag-from-innerhtml) that loop through the scripts manually and run eval on each, but this still wouldn't load external scripts, eg `<script src="...`

I know that [jQuery's `load` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will do exactly what I want, but I want to know how to do it with Angular. Is it possible?