# how to load script and its function dynamically in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Initially I kept below code statically in Index.html and it works.

```
<script src="/le.min.js"></script>
<script>
    LE.init({
        token: 'token',
        region: 'x'
    });
</script>
```

due to my requirement I decided to load dynamically for that I wrote sample code.

```
//loads librabry
jsScript = document.createElement('script');
jsScript.src = `/le.min.js`;
document.head[0].appendChild(jsScript);

//loads initialise function in the script
script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHtml= `LE.init({
                    token: '${TOKEN}',
                    region: 'US'
                   });`
document.head[0].appendChild(script);
```

both are appending rightly but it throwing error `LE is not defined`.If I append the initialise func script as `type=text` no error but no initialise would happen. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: The script file probably isnt loaded yet, therefore LE is not defined. You'll need to use the onload event: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-the-onload-event-on-script-tag

Comment: I believe you need an `onload` event handler for the first script

Comment: use Angular safe pipe implementation DomSanitizer(bypassSecurityTrustScript)

Comment: I hope could be helpful this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547505/angular-2-how-to-execute-script-tag-from-innerhtml

Comment: I'm calling those in  `ngAfterViewInit` what `onload` would help me here in angular ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to **load a script dynamically in Angular** is to use the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class. First inject it in your constructor, then use it to add your script to document's head tag.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
  script.src = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/le_js/0.0.3/le.min.js`;
  this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, script);
}
```

The right way to **execute functions from a js script file loaded to your app** is to **declare** (`declare var LE: any;`) this object in your component/service/or any other place you would want to use it. This way you can execute it's function directly instead of using a dynamic script.

Once it is declared you can use it directly, see this example code:

```
declare var LE: any;

initLE() {
  LE.init({
    token: '${TOKEN}',
    region: 'US'
  });
}

log() {
  LE.log("Hello, logger!");
}
```

> Check out this [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-using-js-script-object-in-component)

You can see that in this DEMO I'm reaching to LE code, but obviously it is not working because of the missing token.

**Full example Code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

declare var LE: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/le_js/0.0.3/le.min.js`;
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, script);
  }

  initLE() {
    LE.init({
      token: '${TOKEN}',
      region: 'US'
    });
  }

  log() {
    LE.log("Hello, logger!");
  }
}
```