# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined when parsing script in innerhtml

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am parsing scripts in inner HTML in angular which I have referred in this link 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547505/angular-2-how-to-execute-script-tag-from-innerhtml)

My code is

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-html-viz',
  templateUrl: './html-viz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./html-viz.component.css'],

})
export class HtmlVizComponent implements OnInit ,OnChanges{

  constructor(public sanitzer:DomSanitizer) { }
  @Input() data;
  @Input() reportOptions
  innerHtml
  @ViewChild('htmlContainer') container;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges)
  { if(changes.reportOptions)
    {
      this.setInnerHtml()
    }
  }
  setInnerHtml()
  {
     if(this.reportOptions.htmlRes)
     { let final=this.reportOptions.htmlRes
       this.innerHtml=this.sanitzer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(final)
       setTimeout(()=>{
        let scripts = this.container.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('script');
        for (let script of scripts){
          eval(script.text)
        }
       })

     }
  }

}
```

usage `<div #htmlContainer *ngIf="innerHtml"  [innerHTML]="innerHtml"></div>`

In this code, I am getting an HTML response from the API and I am parsing the script tag and displaying the HTML output.
when doing so, I am getting the error like this

```
errors.ts:35 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (html-viz.component.ts:34), <anonymous>:3:3636)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (html-viz.component.ts:34), <anonymous>:5:22947)
    at html-viz.component.ts:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:262)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

I don't know where the code breaks

I have added my HTML response in a file, here is the link [here](https://jmp.sh/bGDrMEQ)

Can someone help me out with the solution or is there any other way to parse HTML in angular

thanks in advance:)

Comment: Show your script's content

Comment: Hi David, just added the response in a file please, look into it

Comment: @DaraniShanmugam Don't add a link to a file. Add the contents to your question.

Comment: @Silvermind actually it contains more number of lines that is the reason I added link

Comment: @DaraniShanmugam Nobody should download files from untrusted sources. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)