# Angular DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml not executing script tag inside html content

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml, angular-dom-sanitizer

I tried to use DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml, the html content looks as below:

```
<div>
  <div id="test-div">
    It is a test div element.
  </div>
  <script>
    function changeColor() {
      document.getElementById('test-div').style.background='red';
    }
    changeColor();
  </script>
</div>
```

Everything works here except the script tag code.  Any leads are highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to apply \[ngStyle\] conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280975/angular-how-to-apply-ngstyle-conditions)

Comment: @NarenMurali Please read the title carefully.

Comment: Take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825383